# How to stop reporting FAILED of systemctl unit

Tags: service, systemctl

I have an systemctl service unit which has some runtime dependencies which get resolved during boot. Many times it reports "FAILED" state during boot.  This service unit has "Restart=always", so ultimately after boot this unit starts successfully. But, during boot around 3-4 times it reports FAILED which I want to avoid.

Is there a way to ignore the "FAILED" state of service unit being reported?
(As I know it will succeed once the dependency is resolved or will keep retrying)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the return value (including error) reported by failure of service unit can be ignored prepending an hyphen while configuring the ExecStart.

From manual:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#BusName=

VIZ:

"-" If the executable path is prefixed with "-", an exit code of the command normally considered a failure (i.e. non-zero exit status or abnormal exit due to signal) is recorded, but has no further effect and is considered equivalent to success.

ExecStart=-/sbin/getty